# Recasting specific dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame of three columns:`title`, `text` and `grp`.

The data frame looks like this:

| title | text | grp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Week 2** | In Week 2 the encoding... | 2 |
| comments | *collection of comments about **Week 2*** | 2 |
| **Statistics** | Statistics is the discipline... | 3 |
| comments | *collection of comments about **Statistics*** | 3 |

I want to add the `comments` as columns to this dataframe and keep the value as its text corresponding to each title.

desired dataframe:

| title | text | comments | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Week 2** | In Week 2 the encoding... | *colection of comments about **Week 2*** | 2 |
| **Statistics** | Statistics is the discipline... | *collection of comments about **Statistics*** | 3 |

I tried re-casting:

```
library(reshape2)

recast(df, text ~ comment, id.var = c("text"))
```

But gives me an error:

```
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```r
library(dplyr , warn.conflicts = FALSE)

cdf <- df %>% filter(title == "comments") %>%  select( text, grp) 

colnames(cdf)[1] <- "comments"

nocdf <- df %>% select(title , text , grp) %>% filter(title != "comments")

new_df <- right_join(nocdf , cdf , by = "grp")

new_df %>% relocate(grp , .after = last_col())
#>        title                            text
#> 1     Week.2       In.Week.2.the.encoding...
#> 2 Statistics Statistics.is.the.discipline...
#>                                  comments grp
#> 1     collection.of.comments.about.Week.2   2
#> 2 collection.of.comments.about.Statistics   3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could try to `split` every two rows and `cbind`.

```
split(dat, 1:2) |> {\(.) cbind(.$`1`, comments=.$`2`[, 2])}()
#        title                            text grp                                comments
# 1     Week 2       In Week 2 the encoding...   2     collection of comments about Week 2
# 3 Statistics Statistics is the discipline...   3 collection of comments about Statistics
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(title = c("Week 2", "comments", "Statistics", 
"comments"), text = c("In Week 2 the encoding...", "collection of comments about Week 2", 
"Statistics is the discipline...", "collection of comments about Statistics"
), grp = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```